# How to differentiate a parent class which is casted into different child class objects?

Tags: java, oop

I an new to java and am still learning the OOP concepts. I am stuck in a problem. I have 2 java files in order to run the program, and the problem I'm facing is how can I call child class method from a parent class object?

- Parent class has 2 childs - A and B
- What I don't know is when I am returned an object of Parent class, how do I figure out to which child was it casted and then run the subsequent method?
  The work I have done till now:

**Test Package**

```
package test;

public class Parent{
    private String name;

    public void setName(String a){this.name = a;}
    public String getName(String a){return this.name;}

    Parent(String a){
        this.name = a;
    }
}
```

Child class A:

```
package test;

public class ChildA extends Parent{
    private int scoreA;

    public void setScoreA(int a){this.scoreA = a;}
    public int getScoreA(int a){return this.scoreA;}

    ChildA(String a, int b){
        super(a);
        this.scoreA = b;
    }
}
```

Child Class B

```
package test;

public class ChildB extends Parent {
    private int scoreB;
    
    public void setScoreB(int a){this.scoreB = a;}
    public int getScoreB(int a){return this.scoreB;}

    ChildB(String a, int b){
        super(a);
        this.scoreB = b;
    }
}
```

**Test 2 Package**

```
import test;

public class Validate{
    public Parent checkDetail(String a, String b, int c){
        if(b.equals("A")){
            Parent p = new ChildA(a,b,c);
            return p;
        }
        else if(b.equals("B")){
            Parent p = new ChildB(a,b,c);
            return p;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

**Main Package**

```
import test;
import test2.Validate;
import java.util.*;

public class User{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type: ");
        String type = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Score: ");
        int score = sc.nextInt();
        Validate v = new Validate();
        Parent p = v.checkDetail(name,type,score);
        if(p==null)
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        //WHAT I WANT TO DO
        /* If Parent object p returns child of type A, then run method score A
        else if of type B, then run method score B*/
    }
}
```

Few Things to add:

- I can't change the variable names for attributes of either of the class. So if a child has attribute A, the I have to call getA(). I can't use abstract function there.
- There are many more functions in there. I just reproduced a small part of it in order to highlight my problem.
- There is a way to define abstract method for the attributes in parent class, but in my case there are multiple attributes in multiple classes, so writing an abstract method for each one of them would be a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just something like:

```java
if (p instanceof ChildA) {
    ((ChildA)p).setScoreA(something);
} else if (p instanceof ChildB) {
    ((ChildB)p).setScoreB(something);
}
```